# jQuery Mobile dialog and Backbone js

Tags: jquery-mobile, backbone.js

I have a backbone app using jquery mobile. I am trying to use a dialog popup however the problem is when i click the link #popupSuccess it doesn't activate the modal because i assume backbone is trapping it. Any ideas?

This is my modal code

```
<a class="modalLink" id="modalSuccessTrigger" href="#popupSuccess" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-transition="pop" data-icon="delete" data-theme="b">Success</a>

<div data-role="popup" id="popupSuccess" data-overlay-theme="a" data-theme="c" data-dismissible="false" style="max-width:400px;" class="ui-corner-all modalLinkCont">
    <div data-role="header" data-theme="a" class="ui-corner-top">
        <h1>Correct!</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content" data-theme="d" class="ui-corner-bottom ui-content" style="background-color:white">
        <h3 class="ui-title">That is correct. Tap to continue to level 2</h3>
        <a href="#" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-rel="back" data-transition="flow" data-theme="b">Contineu</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please post the relevant JavaScript.

Comment: @ScootaP you should trap the link click with the view events `{"a click":"activateModal"}` where activateModal is a method on the view that handles the modal display ex: `$("#modaldiv").dialog()`

Comment: Based on your markup above, you've encountered difficulties opening a `popup` right?

Answer (score 4):

You need to programmatically initiate the popup:

In your backbone view:

```
events: {
   'click #modalSuccessTrigger': 'openPopUp'
},

openPopUp: function(e) {
   e.preventDefault()
   $('#modalSuccessTrigger').popup('open')
}
```

for more details refer to doc: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0-alpha.1/docs/pages/popup/index.html

Answer (score 0):

To handle this issue I use to prevent the backbone routing and activate the popup handling for links marked as `data-rel="popup"`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  ($('a[data-rel="popup"]')).on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    var target = $(this).attr("href");
    $(target).popup('open');
  });
});
```